# Scope and destruction of objects in Java and Android

Tags: java, android, performance, greendao

During the first launch (after the installation) of my Android application I create nearly 1000 objects and then save them in an SQLite database through greenDAO ORM. I'm new to Java programming and I'd like to ask if I can get better performance by putting in brackets in order to invoke object destruction through the garbage collector.

The code is:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = new Foo();
Foo foo3 = new Foo();
Foo foo4 = new Foo();
.
.
.
Foo foo1000 = new Foo();
```

And the idea for destroying objects in memory through scopes is:

```
{
   Foo foo1 = new Foo();
   Foo foo2 = new Foo();
}
{
    Foo foo3 = new Foo();
    Foo foo4 = new Foo();
}
{
    .
    .
    .
    Foo foo1000 = new Foo();
}
```

So my idea is that the garbage collector frees objects from memory right after passing each bracket. If this is not the right way, what is your suggestion to achieve better performance in this scenario?

Comment: Invoking GC more often will not increase performance.  It may increase *perceived* performance (smoothness) by replacing a few long GC operations with more shorter ones, but the overall execution time will increase.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, if you don't ever need to simultaneously hold multiple instances of your class, you might as well create one object and re-use it 1000 times.

```
Foo my_foo = new Foo();

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
    my_foo.setValue(i);
    saveToDB(my_foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If those 1000 objects are always created the same you may want to distribute your application with a pre-populated database. There is a good [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) library to do that.

Comment: in my scenario i'm using greenDAO and this ORM dosen't support pre-populated database.

Comment: You can create your Green DAO database once in your program and then use that as a prepopulated database. Pull it from the phone by adb pull and then create a prepopulated db with it.